# Talend Bulk load data conversion error on Boolean field

Tags: talend

I have a Talend job that uses MS SQL Bulk load:

[image]

I'm mapping a boolean field in this way:

[image]

and here is the boolean variable `isVisible` assignation:

[image]

On executing the job, I get this error:

```
Exception in component tMSSqlBulkExec_1 (produits)
java.sql.SQLException: Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 126 (isVisible).
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1282)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.tMSSqlBulkExec_1Process(produits.java:25289)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.tMSSqlInput_6Process(produits.java:24970)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.tMSSqlConnection_1Process(produits.java:2595)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.tMSSqlConnection_3Process(produits.java:2430)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.runJobInTOS(produits.java:44123)
    at elcom.produits_0_6.produits.main(produits.java:43718)
```

However, the value is the CSV file seems to be correct:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is having trouble recognizing `"true"` and `"false"` literals as booleans. Try using an integer (or byte) type in your output; and mapping it with 0 (for false) and 1 (for true).